# Magento - adding a new field to the product options in admin

Tags: magento

I'd like to add a new tab to the 'catalog->manage products->product information' page in the admin. Underneath the 'images' tab, I'd like to add a new tab for video, with a simple text input for adding a video url, which I can then grab for the frontend.

Anyone any ideas where the files are that I need to edit? I've been looking for the last couple hours with no joy. I found the list of current options in Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup but can't figure out how to add to them...

Seems it gets some from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs. If I copy one of the tab sections here and change the title to Video, I can get it to display in the tabs on the left. But how do I then add the options for it?

Comment: Did u got the solution for this? I have followed as explained below. But no use. Let me know the correct solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your other comments, for the URLs a simple attribute would work but files would tend to be more difficult. To add a custom tab, as you said, you can edit (or in the case of a plugin, override) `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs::_prepareLayout` and add your tab. You'll need to add a block or template to display your tab contents.

After that, you'll need to store the data somewhere. Looking in `Adminhtml/controllers/ProductController`, you should be able to hook into the `catalog_product_prepare_save` event to get data from `$event->getRequest()` and push it onto the product or save another entity as necessary.

I'm not sure how well file saving semantics would work on a product, so you may want to do your own data storage in the extension and then provide something like a `getVideoForProduct` method to retrieve it.

Then the only thing left to do is modify the `catalog/product/view.phtml` template file to include your thumbs and create a controller in your extension to provide a modal w/ the video (or do it in JS).

I know that's a bit of a general answer, but it's the rough path you would need to take for tabs. Let me know if any specific part of that is unclear.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do, from the sounds of it, is to create a custom field and add it to your catalog data. The good news is that you don't need to muck around in the PHP for that.

Head to Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes and create a new attribute for yourself called "Video URL" (or something to that effect). This will probably be a text field, and you may want to hide it from comparison on the frontend of the site (select "No" for all those boxes at the bottom of the form).

Once you've created an attribute, you will need to add it to an attribute set. If all your products are of one "type", and if you didn't create any other attribute sets, this should be only one step. Head to Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attribute Sets and create a "New Group" called "Video" and drag your new video url attribute into it. Save the attribute set and you should now have your new tab.

The only complication from what I read in your post could be positioning it underneath the images tab. Magento adds several tabs statically (the long way, in the PHP) and doesn't generally obey ordering of the tab groups. Consider the time tradeoff.

Hope that helps. Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Thanks for that Joe - I thought about doing it as an attribute first, but I don't think I can upload any files then can I? I was planning on having an upload form to add a thumbnail for each video, and have the video open in a modal window on the frontend. Also, I'll probably be using this on numerous sites so would be easier as an extension that I can just drop in.