# Add a custom field to product and in front end option to filter acording to this filed

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to add a new filed in 'catalog->manage products->product information'
say "Age". It will be droppdown (**Compulsory** field). values can be 0-6 month, 1-2 year, 2-5 year etc

In front end just like there is a box for showing Categories there will be another box showing these values i.e. 0-6 month, 1-2 year, 2-5 years etc
When user will click on these links it will list only particular products having same vale for Age.

I have found:

- [Magento - adding a new field to the product options in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136515/magento-adding-a-new-field-to-the-product-options-in-admin)
- [Magento - adding a new field to the product options in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136515/magento-adding-a-new-field-to-the-product-options-in-admin)

As you can see they are not enough for my work.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the attribute for "age" make sure that "Use In Layered Navigation" is set to yes.
More info http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields

Comment: It is now "yes" and is appearing in front end when we visit categories. But problem is when we do advanced searched.

Comment: If you set "Use in Advanced Search" to yes, then it will show up there as well.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site? what theme are you using?